# How I solve this IndexError?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

My problem is that I need to change this Java code to python:

```
public static byte x1=0,x2=0,x3=0,x4=0,x5=0,x6=0;
```

which is in Java code to python

*jammon* said to me that I can put all that in only this line:

```
x = [0]*6
```

But Now when I run the code I see this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 62, in <module> # The line 62 is the location of x[0]=datosOEM[k];
    x[0]=datosOEM[k];
IndexError:bytearray index out of range
```

I already looked other posts but I do not get it yet.This is part of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
datosOEM=bytearray(5)
print(datosOEM)
datosOEM[0]=65
print(datosOEM)
x=[0]*6
k=0; 
trama=1; 
B=0; 
C=0; 
conexion=True;
resp=0                 
if(conexion):
    #{
    print ('conexion ON')
    while(resp<200):
        print ('data save')
        while(C==0):
            #{
            print ('what is C?')
            x[0]=datosOEM[k];
            if(x[0]==1):
                #{
                print ('what is x[0]?')
                x[1]=datosOEM[k+1];
                if((x[1]&1)==1):
                    #{
                    print ('what is x[1]?')
                    C=1;
                    #}
                #}
            k=k+1;
            #}
        k=k-1;
        ...
```

To be clear, my question is: **How can I create some bytearrays in python that are not out of range?**

I appreciate every support that you can give me with this.

Please, Do not be tough with me I am just learning

Comment: Your `[0]*6` __should__ work. If not, try: `[0 for i in range(6)]`

Comment: Probably the problem is `datosOEM[k]` not the `x[0]`.

Comment: [0 for i in range(6)] not work either.                              The code is public static byte[]  datosOEM = new byte[900000];        then I change it follow instructions of Craig and user3286261.

Comment: can you show the whole code. The problem is in the parts you don't show. As a good advice: Python is something different to java: - conditions don't need braces and commands aren't terminated with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem, I changed the if a little bit I changed

```
if(x[0]==1):
if((x[1]&1)==1):
```

to

```
if(x[0]==0):
if((x[1]&1)==0):
```

and in this way I could fix the problem